# Cannot build .Net core 2.2 project? The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I just install the newest .Net core at this moment.

```
PS C:\temp> dotnet --version
2.2.301
```

And I created a new console project.

```
PS C:\temp> dotnet new console
```

---

> ### Welcome to .NET Core!
>
> Learn more about .NET Core: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
>   Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs
>
> ### Telemetry
>
> The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous and doesn't include command-line arguments. The data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.
>
> Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry
>
> ### ASP.NET Core
>
> Successfully installed the ASP.NET Core HTTPS Development Certificate.
>   To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only). For establishing trust on other platforms refer to the platform specific documentation.
>   For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
>   Getting ready...
>   The template "Console Application" was created successfully.
>
> Processing post-creation actions...
>   Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\temp\temp.csproj...
>     Restore completed in 190.58 ms for C:\temp\temp.csproj.
>
> Restore succeeded.

---

However, `dotnet run` got the following error?

```
PS C:\temp> dotnet run
C:\Users\wangyi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,20): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(10,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(13,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
C:\Users\wangyi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,71): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
C:\Users\wangyi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,99): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FrameworkDisplayName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
C:\Users\wangyi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,122): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(10,55): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,61): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,59): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(13,68): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,55): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,53): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,55): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
C:\Users\wangyi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
C:\Users\wangyi\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\temp.AssemblyInfo.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
Program.cs(5,11): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
Program.cs(7,26): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]
Program.cs(7,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported [C:\temp\temp.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

Running `dotnet restore` didn't get any error.

```
PS C:\temp> dotnet restore
Restore completed in 41.15 ms for C:\temp\temp.csproj.
```

I tried "deleting the C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" (https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1006) but it still didn't resolve the issue.

However, in visual studio, the project compiles and runs after I switch the .net core version of the project to **2.1**.

Comment: I found it too and tried "deleting the C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" mentioned in the link but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone today. I tried to install the newest .Net core SDK and it still didn't resolve the problem.

Then I launched VS 2019 and created a new .Net core project in VS. And it compiles. And I go back to the powershell and found out `dotnet run` works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
dotnet restore
```

Then it should work, or at least give you information about the reason why the dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: No, it still gets the errors after `dotnet restore`. (btw, I think `dotnet new console` will restore the project at the end?)

Comment: Wasn't sure, but normally it fixes my issues. But what are the dotnet restore errors?

Comment: `dotnet restore` doesn't have any error. The project cannot be compiled.

Comment: Are you able to run your console app from visual studio?

Comment: @Ray, no, running in Visual Studio has the same problem.

Comment: Could you try clean the sln in vs and rebuild?

Comment: If you just installed the sdk you might want to consider a reboot... but i haven't needed that once.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, I rebooted after installed .Net core 2.2 SDK. It prompted a dialog box for rebooting.

Comment: I am out of options... I'll leave the answer for now because of the discussion in comments

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt you can write: dotnet --version and you will see your current version. I recommend you download the core framework from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) instead of installing through the visual studio installer. Installing .net core from the site fixed my problems.

Comment: I downloaded from the first link of google search result. I think it should be the link in your answer. `dotnet --version` shows 2.2.301 after I installed V2.2. However, V2.1 projects work without problem.

Comment: You can try to delete bin and obj and rebuild it. Sometimes it helps with build errors.